# SQL запрос к другой таблице к полям с ключом

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы с разными полями. В первой таблице:

- `ID`
- `FIO`
- `Person_Supplier` - внешний ключ

Вторая таблица:

- `Supplier_ID` - первичный ключ
- `Supplier_Type`
- `Supplier_City`

Как можно сделать запрос `SELECT` чтобы он выводил значения равные `Person_Supplier` и `Supplier_ID` и обязательно чтобы `Supplier_Type` был определённого значения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT        Persons.*
FROM            Persons INNER JOIN
  Suppliers ON Persons.Person_Supplier = Suppliers.Supplier_ID
WHERE        (Suppliers.Supplier_Type = 'Юридическое лицо')
```